# ITextSharp v5.5.13.0 XMLWorker Turkish character problem

Tags: itext

I used iTextSharp and all Turkish character disappeared.
Also html inline css attributes work on table element but not working on div element.

I tried lots of encoding convert sample code but not found any results.

My sample code:

```
public static byte[] HtmlToPdfItextSharp(string HTMLCONTENTSTRING, List<string> cssFiles = null)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);

        BaseFont STF_Helvetica_Turkish = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, "CP1254", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        Font fontNormal = new Font(STF_Helvetica_Turkish, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);


        string fontPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/arial.ttf")));
        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        fontProvider.UseUnicode = true;
        fontProvider.Register(fontPath);
        CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);

        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);

        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfWriter.DirectContent.SetFontAndSize(STF_Helvetica_Turkish, 12);
        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

        var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
        cssFiles.ForEach(e => cssResolver.AddCssFile(e, true));

        var pp = new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDoc, pdfWriter);
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pp));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(worker);


        parser.Parse(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTMLCONTENTSTRING)));

        pdfDoc.Close();

        return ms.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing all kinds of things that shouldn't be mixed: `pdfWriter.DirectContent.SetFontAndSize(STF_Helvetica_Turkish, 12);` doesn't make sense in the context of HTML to PDF. `(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, "CP1254")` doesn't make sense because Times Roman doesn't have all the Turkish glyphs, and so on. You're using a *maintenance* release of an old iText version that is only supported for paying customers. Upgrade to iText 7 + pdfHTML https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/which-languages-are-supported-pdfhtml

Comment: In short: XMLWorker has been replaced by pdfHTML in iText 7. See the [introduction of the HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code and add stylesheet file (with font familiy:arial;) and i solved character
but it takes too long time 
    My new updated function like:

```
public static byte[] HtmlToPdfItextSharp(string HTMLCONTENTSTRING, List<string> cssFiles = null)
{
    using (var ms= new MemoryStream())
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 7, 10);

        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);
        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
        pdfDoc.Open();

        var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
        cssFiles.ForEach(e => cssResolver.AddCssFile(e, true));

        var pp = new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDoc, pdfWriter);
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pp));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(worker);
        parser.Parse(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pHtmlIcerik)));

        pdfDoc.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Css code :

```
 body {
     font-family:Arial;
}
table{
    font-family:Arial;
}
td{
    font-family:Arial;
}
```